# How to fix this SML code to work as intended?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

Right now I have an SML function:

```
method([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]);
```

returns:

```
val it = [[2,2,2],[3,3,3]] : int list list
```

but I need it to return:

```
val it = [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]] : int list list
```

This is my current code:

```
- fun method2(L: int list) = 
= if tl(L) = [] then [hd(L)] else  
= if hd(tl(L)) = hd(L) then hd(L)::method(tl(L)) else [hd(L)];

- fun method(L: int list) = 
= if tl(L) = [] then [] else
= if hd(tl(L)) = hd(L) then method(tl(L)) else
= method2(tl(L))::method(tl(L));
```

As you can see it misses the first method2 call. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I am completely stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `if hd(tl(L)) = hd(L) then method(tl(L)) else`.  This is saying if the head of the tail is equal to the head, then continue processing, but don't add it to the result list.  this will skip the first contiguous chunk of equal values.  I would suggest separating the duties of these functions a bit more.  The way to do this is to have `method2` strip off the next contiguous chunk of values, and return a pair, where the first element will have the contiguous chunk removed, and the second element will have the remaining list.  For example, `method2([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]) = ([1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 3, 3])` and `method2([2, 2, 3, 3]) = ([2, 2], [3, 3])`.  Now, you can just keep calling `method2` until the second part of the pair is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do with your code. I would recommend creating a tail recursive helper function which is passed three arguments:

```
1) The list of lists you are trying to build up
2) The current list you are building up
3) The list you are processing
```

In your example, a typical call somewhere in the middle of the computation would look like:

```
helper([[1,1,1,1]], [2,2],[2,3,3,3])
```

The recursion would work by looking at the head of the last argument (`[2,3,3,3]`) as well as the head of the list which is currently being built up (`[2,2]`) and, since they are the same -- the 2 at the end of the last argument is shunted to the list being built up:

```
helper([[1,1,1,1]], [2,2,2],[3,3,3])
```

in the next step in the recursion the heads are then compared and found to be different (2 != 3), so the helper function will put the middle list at the front of the list of lists:

```
helper([[2,2,2], [1,1,1,1]], [3],[3,3])
```

the middle list is re-initialized to [3] so it will start growing

eventually you reach something like this:

helper([[2,2,2], [1,1,1,1]], [3,3,3],[])

the [3,3,3] is then tacked onto the list of lists and the *reverse* of this list is returned.

Once such a helper function is defined, the main method checks for an empty list and, if not empty, initializes the first call to the helper function. The following code fleshes out theses ideas -- using pattern-matching style rather than `hd` and `tl` (I am not a big fan of using those functions explicitly -- it makes the code too Lisp-like). If this is homework then you should probably thoroughly understand how it works and then translate it to code involving `hd` and `tl` since your professor would regard it as plagiarized if you use things you haven't yet studied and haven't made it your own work:

```
fun helper (xs, ys, []) = rev (ys::xs)
|   helper (xs, y::ys, z::zs) = 
        if y = z 
           then helper(xs, z :: y :: ys, zs)
           else helper((y::ys)::xs,[z],zs);

fun method [] = []
|   method (x::xs) = helper([],[x],xs);
```